# Maven, JavaFX and class file has wrong version

Tags: java, maven, javafx

when I compile with maven, I got the following:

```
cannot access com.sun.javafx.scene.control.LabeledImpl
 bad class file:
[...]/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/11/javafx-controls-11-linux.jar(com/sun/javafx/scene/control/LabeledImpl.class)
   class file has wrong version 54.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

I know this error has been posted several times, but I didn't find something related to maven (here, the class version problem is for a file into the .m2 directory of maven).

In my pom.xml, I have:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
  <version>11</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```xml
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: JavaFX 11 targets java 11. No wonder compilation with a target version of 1.8 fails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are trying to reach java fx 11 with java 8. Probably you need java 11

Comment: Why does the error speak about class file having wrong version? I wish it somehow hinted at the real problem. Good thing there's the internet, SO and GitHub issues.

Comment: Apparently the error wasn't about the `.java` file containing a class but the actual `.class` file. The class file has a range of versions that it supports and there exists an (odd) mapping between class versions and java versions.